# Hibernate keeps updating database even when I work with local variables

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I encountered an issue, where the items from my database get deleted at a certain point. It seems like Hibernate updates the database when I'm working with local variables.

Here is my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        " http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- MySQL Configuration -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">dbname</property>
        <property name="connection.username">dbusername</property>
        <property name="connection.password">dbpassword</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="model.User"/>
        <mapping class="model.Admin"/>
        <mapping class="model.Student"/>
        <mapping class="model.Teacher"/>
        <mapping class="model.Classroom"/>
        <mapping class="model.Quiz"/>
        <mapping class="model.Task"/>
        <mapping class="model.Solution"/>
        <mapping class="model.CorrectSolution"/>
        <mapping class="model.WrongSolution"/>
        <mapping class="model.Result"/>


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I'll post a few examples of code where items get deleted.

This is my own ComboBox class, I save objects of `Quiz` class in it and I want to remove every `Quiz` which has an empty `TaskList`.

```
private void removeEmptyQuizzes(List<Quiz> quizList){
    for(Quiz q : quizList){
        if(q.getTaskList().isEmpty()){
            quizList.remove(q);
        }
    }
    setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(quizList));
}
```

What happens is that all `Quizzes` with empty `TaskList` get completely deleted from the database, not just from the `ComboBox`.

My application is a Quiz test game, so here's another example. I load the tasks into a `List<Task>` and then I remove the

```
private void fillTaskList(){
    taskList = SelectedQuiz.getQuiz().getTaskList();
    taskNumber = taskList.size();
}
  private void loadTask(){
            if(!taskList.isEmpty()) {
        int taskIndex = new Random().nextInt(taskList.size());

        task = taskList.get(taskIndex);

        // extra stuff for my quiz - not relevant to the question
        /*view.getLbQuestion().setText(task.getQuestion());

        List<AnswerBox> answerBoxList = createAnswerBoxList();
        List<Solution> solutionList = createSolutionList(task);
        int bound = answerBoxList.size();

        for(AnswerBox box : answerBoxList){
            int index = (new Random().nextInt(bound) + 1) - 1;
            Solution sol = solutionList.get(index);
            box.setSolution(sol);
            solutionList.remove(sol);
            bound--;
        }*/

        taskList.remove(taskList.get(taskIndex));
    }
    else {
        Student student = (Student) LoggedInUtil.getLoggedInUser();

        Quiz quiz = SelectedQuiz.getQuiz();

        Result result = new Result(correctAnswers, wrongAnswers, student, quiz.getName());

        new ResultDao().insertResult(result);

        rootView.setEndMiddle(taskNumber, correctAnswers, wrongAnswers);
    }
}
```

Now, I have `Tasks` saved in the database. However, they all get deleted when I call this `new ResultDao().insertResult(result);` function. I tried sysouting `Quiz.getTaskList.size()` in the final `else` (before saving the `Result`) and it indeed was 0 and Hibernate updated it.

Now, why does Hibernate automatically update my variables? I have specific `Dao` classes to work with database, but I don't call them in these cases.

I appreciate all answers, thank you.

EDIT: added `InsertResult()` method on request

```
public void insertResult(Result r) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(r);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

EDIT2: added mapping for `Result` class

```
@Entity
public class Result {

private int result_id, correctAnswers, wrongAnswers;

private Student student;

private SimpleStringProperty quizName = new SimpleStringProperty();

public Result() {
}

public Result(int correctAnswers, int wrongAnswers, Student student, String quizName) {
    this.correctAnswers = correctAnswers;
    this.wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers;
    this.student = student;
    this.quizName.set(quizName);
}

@Column(nullable = false)
public int getCorrectAnswers() {
    return correctAnswers;
}

public void setCorrectAnswers(int correctAnswers) {
    this.correctAnswers = correctAnswers;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
public int getWrongAnswers() {
    return wrongAnswers;
}

public void setWrongAnswers(int wrongAnswers) {
    this.wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers;
}

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="id" , strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="id")
public int getResult_id() {
    return result_id;
}

public void setResult_id(int result_id) {
    this.result_id = result_id;
}

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Student.class)
public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}

public void setStudent(Student student) {
    this.student = student;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
public String getQuizName() {
    return quizName.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty quizNameProperty() {
    return quizName;
}

public void setQuizName(String quizName) {
    this.quizName.set(quizName);
}

@Transient
public SimpleStringProperty studentWithClassProperty(){
    String studentWithClass = getStudent().getName() + getStudent().getSurname() + " - " + getStudent().getClassroom().toString();
    return new SimpleStringProperty(studentWithClass);
}
```

}

Comment: I hope your user and password in the hibernate config are fake.

Comment: @Redblad Of course

Comment: Perhaps include the code related to `ResultDao#insertResult`.

Comment: @Naros Edited the question, the part of the code is there. However, I'm 100% sure the method is not causing it. I tried adding a "test" Result in my  main class and there were no issues. I'm certain it's because the `taskList` (and other local variables) were changed.

Comment: Can you please show the hibernate mapping of Result

Comment: @simas_ch Added. But I still don't think the issue lies there, as I've been getting basically same issues in different parts of my code where `Result` class was not used at all.